# Opening external links from select/option dropdown in a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, external-links

I have a select-option dropdown with links, both internal and external. I want the external links (and only them) to open in a new tab. This is what I have.

```
<select id="my-dropdown">
    <option value="">A list of internal and external links</option>
    <option value="http://www.someurl.com">External Link</option>
    <option value="/internal/page">Internal links</option>
</select>
```

JS to open the links.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("my-dropdown").onchange = function() {
        if (this.selectedIndex!==0) {
            window.location.href = this.value;
        }        
    };
</script>
```

EDIT: Changing the JS to this does it:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("my-dropdown").onchange = function() {

        var externalLinkCheck = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

        if (this.selectedIndex!==0 && externalLinkCheck.substring(0,4) == "http") {
            window.open(this.value, '_blank');
        } else {
            window.location.href = this.value;
        }        
    };
</script>
```

[chriserwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673269/chriserwin)'s answer below is also good! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add another condition that looks for the `http://` prefix of the external links.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("my-dropdown").onchange = function() {
        if (this.selectedIndex!==0) {
            if (this.value.indexOf('http://') == 0) {
                window.open(this.value);
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = this.value;
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

However most browsers have a popup blocker that will close new windows opened programatically. Usually only code that is handling an onclick event will be allowed to bypass the popup blocker.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
<script>
   document.getElementById("my-dropdown").onchange = function() {
      if(this.selectedIndex!==0) {
          var win=window.open(this.value, '_blank');
          win.focus();
      }        
   };
</script>
```

Comment: does this check if this is an external or internal link?

Comment: It's an external link.!!

Comment: Please read the question above. Internal links should open in the current tab and external links should open in a new tab. I don't think your code checks? Or am I wrong?